# Basic image Target android apk not working, watermark sticks around and no 3D model showed

Tags: unity-game-engine, apk, augmented-reality, vuforia

In the past, I could build working apks over and over. But recently, I failed to do so. This time, I build a super simple project in Unity using image target to show a cube. The apk generates normally, but when I open the app, it shows watermark, and I have checked my license key is already there.

After the apk pops out, this error flash by
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 3.5.0-dev-20359-01 (8da8ba0c).

When I clicked on the project, it starts to reload some scripts the the error disappears. There only a succuessful message left. No errors, but watermark appears all the time, nothing shown when the camera is filming at the target image.

I have no idea what's happening, I am so desperate for help. I have attached some settings of my project for reference. Thank you very much

Project Structure and Vuforia Config

[image]

Build Setting

[image]

Player Setting

[image]

I have tried both scripting background with mono and iL2CPP, with ARMv7 / ARMV64/ both.

To solve Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 3.5.0-dev-20359-01 (8da8ba0c) this error, i have changed api Compatibility Level to .NET 4.x

I also tried to play with it in play mode, everything works fine.

Comment: This bug happens even on iOS, Unity 2022LTS and Unity 2023 too.
I can only stay in older version of Vuforia.. desperate...

Comment: @imleoson did you find a work around, this is still hapenning i already commented in the following official github repo. https://github.com/PTCInc/vuforia-engine/issues/47, some one mention in SO that on a brand new project the same Vuforia version works, I will test by deleting vuforia form the project and installing it again, hope that could work.

Comment: YES, solved in a tricky way...
I ended up by creating a complete new project, import the latest Vuforia SDK. Then import all my assets from old project to this new project.

Some thoughts:
1. There must be some cached Vuforia files somewhere on my computer which caused this bug.
2. It's hard to do a clean install or upgrade easily. Because when we remove the old version complete, my other Vuforia related scripts will cause errors. Those errors might interrupt the import process of new Vuforia.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my conclusion about the watermark issue on iOS.
What I tried:

- upgrade Vuforia version from existing project.

Not work: some old cache or hidden files from older Vuforia still located somewhere in Mac or Unity project. This cause watermark issue

- remove all related Vuforia files, including library folder and cache in
  Unity project root folder, any vuforia keyword in any config files,
  package manager..etc

Not work: there might be some cache in hidden path in system?

- remove Old Vuforia Assets from project, then import the latest Vuforia

Not work: In my project, there are many other scripts involving Vuforia class. If I remove the old vuforia assets, there will be a lot of errors in consoles.
In this case, those error might interrupt the auto import process of new Vuforia.
As a result, you will have an incomplete Vuforia setup.

- Solution(not suggested, but the only way it works for my case):

1. create a new project, import the latest Vuforia to this empty project
2. export your Assets from old project, as unity package
3. import them into your new Unity project
4. done and test on iOS, watermark issue fixed!
5. *remember to check your project settings, player settings, quality settings and layers as well.

This is obviously a very serious Vuforia bug on Mac or iOS, as long as there is anything interrupt the import process, you will have watermark issue, and it won't be functional as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds symptomatic of using an older version of Engine with a more recent license key. Changes were made in the SDK's logic to remove the watermark for legacy features (i.e. Image Targets). However, older versions of the SDK will still show the watermark, even with newly generated license keys.

Unfortunately, the only way to remove the watermark would be to upgrade the version of Engine SDK.

Comment: What do you mean by Engine SDK, the vuforia engine, or the unity editor. I have Vuforia version 10.16.5 on Unity 2022.3.7f1, also happen when working with Unity 2022.3.5f1.
With the previous version used in that project, vuforia 10.10 all was OK.

Comment: Obviously, Vuforia Engine SDK is not part of the Unity Editor. Thus, when you download our Unity extension (or install the Vuforia Engine Unity samples), Vuforia Engine SDK is also installed. By providing the Vuforia version (same as the Vuforia SDK version), you've confirmed that you're not using an "older version of Engine".

Comment: I suggest that you open an issue here: https://github.com/PTCInc/vuforia-engine/, and provide the license's UUID (different from the key entered into the Unity Editor). This way we can take a closer look at the specific license causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks David, the issue is already open, I mentioned it and linked to it in the comments of the original question in case you didn't noticed. Regards!